# Reset the Kinect sensor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working on a Kinect based project where I want to reset my `Kinect sensor` on a `Button` click event  but there is only two methods `sensor.start()` & `sensor.stop()`. Its like the pausing the sensor and starts it again, it doesn't reset or re-initialize. So, is there any way to achieve this..??

Thanks in advance..

**Edit:**

There is a event handler kinectSensorChooser1 += kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged, this will help me in initializing the new instance of sensor so, I want to call it explicitly in a function.

```
kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
      KinectSensor old = (KinectSensor)e.OldValue;
      StopKinect(old);
      KinectSensor sensor = (KinectSensor)e.NewValue;
}
```

I dont know how to call it because

```
private void ResetSensor()
{
    // this doesn't work like others so what parameters should I pass then..
    kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged(null, null);
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of reseting a kinect sensor?

Comment: When the kinect is in used for a long time, it stops working/detecting or goes into idle like state. For this I have to restart the whole application that I want to avoid..

Comment: This should be possible to avoid without reseting the sensor every once in a while.

Comment: I would recomend to find problem of that it stops working instead of creating a workaround. If you rly want to restart it just reinitialize the sensor object by destroing it and creating a new one

Comment: I'm having problems in reinitializing the sensor object I edited the post and I dont know why kinect behaves like that that's why I opted for this step..

Comment: @SidharthPenta rather than trying to call an event handler from your code, you should create a method to do the work, and then call that method from the event handler/wherever else you you want to call it from.

Comment: @Bridge even if I call this `ResetSensor` method in event handler or somewhere else I need those parameters to re-initialize the sensor

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to reset the sensor.

It sounds like you are using Skeleton Tracking in Seated Mode:

```
this.kinect.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
```

In Seated mode, the Kinect uses movement to detect users.  So if the Skeleton is not tracked (e.g. due to going outside field of view), the user will need to move again so the user can be tracked by the Sensor.  This may give the impression in an application that the Sensor is IDLE.

Comment: Actually that's not the case what I am facing is:
When I run the app and user is interacting and he leaves the `Kinect` sensor field and there is nobody in front of the `Kinect` for a long time [more than `15 mins`] and afterwards when the user comes again/back to interact with the kinect, it doesn't detect the user until 
1) I have to cover the kinect sensor with my hand and remove
2) I restart the app